# Python reading windows disk sector problem

Tags: python, windows, io, disk

I read windows disk sectors via python，but I have encountered some problems
eg :

```html
 f=open('\\\\.\\PHYSICALDRIVE0','rb')
 f.seek(0, 2)
```

Will report an error

Then I tried this

```html
while True:
    print(disk.read(1024),disk.tell())
```

Finally hit an ‘[Errno 13] Permission denied error’, find the last successful ‘disk.tell ()’, it will be fine.

The behaviors of seek, read, and tell are very strange near the end of the windows disk.
What I want to ask is why I am getting an error through python, or will I have problems with this operation?

Comment: Low-level disk I/O has to be sector aligned. Work in 512-byte units.

Comment: But I will also report an error with 512 bytes. error 13

Comment: That's `EPERM` (13). Do you have administrator access, i.e. are you running Python from an elevated command prompt?

Comment: I have admin rights  and i run Python from an elevated command prompt，but 
read to the end EPERM (13)，
windows will have this problem, but ubuntu will not